# "No XS-Ruby-Versions" error message when building Ruby package

Tags: ruby, git-buildpackage

I am trying to build a Ruby package using git-buildpackage. I am getting this error near the end of the process:

```
dh clean --buildsystem=ruby --with ruby
   dh_testdir -O--buildsystem=ruby
   dh_auto_clean -O--buildsystem=ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/gem2deb.rb:17: warning: setting Encoding.default_external
  Entering dh_ruby --clean
No XS-Ruby-Versions: field found in source!
dh_auto_clean: dh_ruby --clean returned exit code 1
make: *** [clean] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
E: Failed autobuilding of package
I: unmounting dev/pts filesystem
I: unmounting proc filesystem
 -> Cleaning COW directory
  forking: rm -rf /var/cache/pbuilder/build//cow.7268 
gbp:error: Couldn't run 'git-pbuilder': git-pbuilder returned 1
```

Here is the `rules` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

PACKAGE = $(shell dh_listpackages)
VERSION = $(shell dpkg-parsechangelog | grep ^Version: | cut -d' ' -f2 \
                | cut -d- -f1)
TMP := debian/$(PACKAGE)

DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
        dh $@ --buildsystem=ruby --with ruby

override_dh_auto_install:
        rsync -C --recursive --links --perms --times -v \
          --exclude-from=debian/exclude.rsync --exclude debian $(CURDIR)/ debian/$(PACKAGE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear. Add the missing `XS-Ruby-Versions` field to the `control` file.